# Having trouble passing an element attribute value to my parent scope function

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble passing a value stored as an attribute from a directive template to my $parent controller through `ng-click`. In the Plunker example here I like the second alter to display the word you click.

In my directive I create the `value` scope item to hold the desired value.

```
angular.module('app.directives.dropTarget', [])
  .directive('dropTarget', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        day: '=',
        index: '=',
        method: '&',
        value: "="
      },
      templateUrl: "calDay.html"
    };
  });
```

and I can pass values through my repeater line (day.date gets passed properly)

```
<drop-target index="$index" day="day" value="value" method="test(day.date, value)"></drop-target>

<div class="calObject droptarget">
    <div class="dayHeader" ng-class="{'currPeriod': day.current, 'notCurrPeriod': !day.current}">
        {{day.date | date:"d"}}
    </div>
    <div class="dayBody">
        <div class="dayExercise" value="{{exercise}}" ng-repeat="item in day.array" ng-click="method(day.date, value)">
            {{item}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENjDqAgRoQnqEFy7XnUM?p=preview)

I'm just having a tough time understanding the flow of data through the directive I think.

Comment: on this one you can get all the words when clicked, it might help
http://plnkr.co/edit/HAnFvpWcO73hre2oKXv2?p=preview

Comment: While demos like plunker are very useful, they are no substitute for code in your SO post.  Please [edit] your question to include the relevant pieces of your code.  For example, include your directive definition and maybe how you are using it.

Comment: @Akis_Tfs your solution is returning all values withing the day, not just the one I cklicked. I'd need to pas in the array index of the specific word.

Comment: Hi, are you looking for this as result? http://plnkr.co/edit/DFDlxacoxqrtZ0eBKMUW?p=preview. I hope this helps. Regards